# how to upload file in codeigniter without submit button?

Tags: php, codeigniter, upload, submit, multipart

I have a script to upload file use codeigniter but it still use submit button. I want to upload without clicking on submit. this is my script:

*controllers/gallery.php*

```
<?php
class Gallery extends CI_Controller{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function index(){
        $this->load->model('MGallery');
        if($this->input->post('upload')){
            $this->MGallery->do_upload();
        }

    $this->load->view('gallery_view');
    }
}
?>
```

*models/mgallery.php*

```
<?php
class MGallery extends CI_Model{

var $gallery_path;

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->gallery_path = realpath(APPPATH . '../images');
}

function do_upload(){
   $config = array(
      'allowed_types'=>'jpg|jpeg|gif|png',
      'upload_path' => $this->gallery_path,
      'max_size' => 2000
   );

    $this->load->library('upload',$config);
    $this->upload->do_upload();
    $image_data = $this->upload->data();

    $config = array(
       'source_image'=> $image_data['full_path'],
       'new_image'=>$this->gallery_path . '/thumbs',
       'maintain_ration'=>true,
       'width'=>160,
       'height'=>120
    );

    $this->load->library('image_lib', $config);
    $this->image_lib->resize();
  }
}
```

*views/gallery_view.php*

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html lang="en-US">

    <head>
        <title>Gallery With CI</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="gallery">
        </div>

        <div id="upload">

            <?php echo form_open_multipart('gallery'); ?>
            <?php echo form_upload('userfile');?>

            <?php echo form_submit('upload','Upload'); ?>
            <?php echo form_close(); ?>

        </div>
 </body>
```

what must i do if i want to make it upload without submit button?

Answer (score 2):

In order to be able to upload your file, you are going to need to trigger some JavaScript functions when file is just browsed. bellow code might help you to do this using JQuery AJAX library.

```
$upload_field_info = array('class' => 'file_upload', 'id' => 'file_upload', 'name' => 'file_upload');
echo form_input($upload_field_info);
```

write a javascript function in your view:

```
$('#file_upload').change(function(){  
var upload_data = $('#file_upload').val()
var post_url = "<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/gallery/upload";
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: post_url,
    data: upload_data,
    datatype: "json",
    success: function(data) 
    {
        $('#upload_result_div').html("<span class=success>File Uploaded!</span>");
    }
});
```

And you are going to need a function named 'upload in your 'gallery' controller!

Comment: would you give me more detail script in each model, view, controller?
i've try solution above, but the image that i upload not stored in the destination folder..
sorry, i'm still newbie..